# Memory allocation clarification required

Tags: c, stm32, iar, stm32l152

Here is the picture of a variable placement in STM32L152VBX memory with IAR IDE (8.30). I am using C.

- `_gprs_inited` is a static variable (8bit),
- `send_data_with_gprs` is a function,
- `_failed_gprs_counter` is a static variable (8bit) declared inside the function.

[image: memroy location]

Does this mean both the variables are allocated in the same address?

I mean since both are 8 bit variables, and the processor is 32bit it can hold those two?

Comment: Is it C++.? You do not have to worry or variables will have distinct storage locations

Comment: Have linker generate the map file, and look what it says. What version of IAR is this?

Comment: I am using IAR 8.30, and it is C

Comment: `0x20001488` is different from `0x20001489`, how can it mean they have the same address? `the processor is 32bit` - processor supports instructions operating on 32-bit registers, but the memory is byte-addressable.

Comment: With the limited information presented in the question my guess is that it is a bug in the presentation of code in the ide, but without a [mcve] it can be nothing more than a guess. Have you considered contacting IAR support?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It is a huge project, and I am not allowed to submit it. I will try with linked map file.